# compare "string1" with comma separated "string2" without splitting

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to match `string1` with comma seperated values in `string2` without splitting `string2`. For example, given:

```
String1: 'abc'
String2: '123,fgh,abc,tg,sd'
```

`string1` should be compared with `string2` and should return true as 'abc' is part of `string2`. Is there any way to do it??

Note. INSTR() doesn't solve this. If `string2 is` : `'123,efabcde,34'` it will return true but I need to compare only with comma separated values ("whole words")

Comment: Hi, Have you tried **INSTR**?

Comment: INSTR wont work if string2 is  : '123,efabcde,34'. it wil return true. But i need to compare only with comma separated values

Comment: then this shall do the job INSTR2(String2, ','||String1||',') OR SUBSTR(String2, 1, LENGTH(String1))=String1 OR SUBSTR(String2, -1* LENGTH(String1) + 1)=','||String1

Comment: @hmmftg I don't think you are right (your second case accepts 'abcd') but I think you should post a corrected solution as answer instead posting it two times as comment.

Comment: @ShreedharMathad - for future reference please **edit your question** to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you

```
INSTR2('123,fgh,abc,tg,sd.com', 'abc')
```

Comment: `INSTR2('123,fghabctg,sd.com', 'abc')` is true, too ,I dont think that is intended by the OP

Comment: then this shall do the job **INSTR2(String2, ','||String1||',')** OR **SUBSTR(String2, 1, LENGTH(String1))=String1**  OR **SUBSTR(String2, -1* LENGTH(String1) + 1)=','||String1**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) function

Here is an **example** for your case:

```
with mydata as (
select '123,fgh,abc,tg,sd' d from dual 
union 
select '123,fgh,abcd,tg,sd' d from dual
union 
select 'abc,123,fgh,abcd,tg,sd' d from dual
union 
select 'abcd,xabc' d from dual
union 
select 'abc' d from dual
)
select d,
case 
   when REGEXP_LIKE(d,',abc,|^abc,|,abc$|^abc$') 
   then 'Y'
   else 'N'
end as res_y_n
from mydata
```

and the **results**:

```
123,fgh,abc,tg,sd       Y
123,fgh,abcd,tg,sd      N
abc                     Y
abc,123,fgh,abcd,tg,sd  Y
abcd,xabc               N
```

Comment: You have '^abc,' but 'abc$' without a comma? That is strange.

Answer (score 0):

If str is the string containing the comma separated list of strings then

- str is equal to abc
- str is equal to abc,...
- str is equal to ...,abc
- str is equal to ...,abc,...

... is an arbitrary string.

You can use string functions, string operators or regular expression to check this. Using string operators you get

```
(str = 'abc') or 
(str like 'abc,%') or 
(str like '%,abc') or 
(str like '%,abc,%')
```

if the string you search for (abc in this example) contains the characters % or _ then you have to quote  them because they have a special meaning in LIKE expressions. You also have to quote the quote character. So if you search for 10% you use

```
(str = '10%') or 
(str like '10\%,%') escape '\' or 
(str like '%,10\%') escape '\' or 
(str like '%,10\%,%') escape '\'
```

A regular expression solution with REGEXP_LIKE looks like more compact then a solution using LIKE or string functions but there are more special characters you have to quote.

If you use string functions (using INSTR, SUBSTR, LENGTH) then there are no special characters but the solution is less compact than this solution using LIKE.